# Trouble casting Error from transaction in SKPaymentTransaction (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nserror

I am trying to get to the error code in a transaction (Swift 3):

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            if let errorCode = (transaction.error as NSError).code {
             //Do something
            }
        }


}
```

I am getting the below error.

> 'Error?' is not convertible to 'NSError'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?`.

Why wont this work? I thought Error could cast to NSError in Swift 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast the `Error` object to `NSError` then access error code.

```
if let nsError = error as? NSError {
    print(nsError.code)
}
```